# How can I set the wrapper of an element's height after the element has been created?

Tags: javascript, class, methods

I created a wrapper in my HTML, `.slider-wrapper`, and using JavaScript, I created an image inside it, so far I've set the image's width to the `.slider-wrapper`'s width and now I want the `.slider-wrapper`'s height to be set to the image's height,

I've already tried doing `sliderWrapper.style.height = sliderWrapper.children.offsetHeight` in the `move()` method but it's not taking effect.

How can I set the `.slider-wrapper`'s height to the image's height when the image is created?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {

    let sliderWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-wrapper')[0];

    class Image {
        sliderWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-wrapper')[0];
        constructor(_src) {
            this.src = _src;
            this.width = window.getComputedStyle(sliderWrapper).width;
            this.move()
        }
    }
    Image.prototype.move = function () {
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute("src", this.src);
        img.style.width = this.width;
        img.classList.add('img');
        sliderWrapper.appendChild(img);
        sliderWrapper.style.height = sliderWrapper.children.offsetHeight;
    }
    let img = new Image('https://via.placeholder.com/150')
});
```

```css
*{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .slider-wrapper{
            position: relative;
            max-width: 800px;
            margin: 70px auto;
            border: 2px solid #ff0000;
        }
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrapper">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the class Image already exists in JS. create your own new class. Then use onload

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
    let sliderWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-wrapper')[0];

    class SlideImage {
        sliderWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-wrapper')[0];
        constructor(_src) {
            this.src = _src;
            this.width = window.getComputedStyle(sliderWrapper).width;
            this.move()
        }
    }
    SlideImage.prototype.move = function () {
      const image = new Image();
      image.src = this.src;
      image.classList.add('img');
      image.onload = function() {
        sliderWrapper.appendChild(image);
        sliderWrapper.style.height = image.height;
        console.log(image.height)
      }
    }
    new SlideImage('https://via.placeholder.com/150')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `img.onload` to check if the `img` has finished loading. Also use `children[0]`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {

  let sliderWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-wrapper')[0];

  class Image {
    sliderWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-wrapper')[0];
    constructor(_src, _id) {
      this.src = _src;
      this.id = _id;
      //remove to get the actual proportions
      // this.width = window.getComputedStyle(sliderWrapper).width;
      this.move()
    }
  }
  Image.prototype.move = function() {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute("src", this.src);
    img.style.width = this.width;
    img.classList.add('img');
    sliderWrapper.appendChild(img);
    img.onload = function() {
      sliderWrapper.style.height = sliderWrapper.children[0].offsetHeight;
    }
  }
  let img = new Image('https://via.placeholder.com/150')
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 70px auto;
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrapper">
</div>
```